# Syntax error in verilog

Tags: syntax-error, system-verilog

I have about six errors but they are all the same. 
The error goes as such: **near "?": syntax error, unexpected '?'**

I've been trying to figure out how to fix this and I've looked at other problems in stackoverflow relating to this problem but to no avail. At first I thought it was how I was formatting my ternary statements but that wasn't it. So what could the prroblem be?

Code:

```
always_ff@(posedge clk, posedge reset)
   if (reset) state <= S0;
   else state <= nextstate;

always_comb
 case (state)
  S0: OpCode1 ? nextstate <= S2 : nextstate <= S1;
  S1: OpCode2 ? nextstate <= S8 : nextstate <= S4;
  S2: OpCode2 ? nextstate <= S3 : nextState <= S9;
  S3: nextstate <= S0;
  S4: A ? nextstate <= S5 : nextstate <= S13;
  S5: B ? nextstate <= S7 : nextstate <= S6;
  S6: Binv ? nextstate <= S14 : nextstate <= S13;
  S7: Binv ? nextstate <= S13 : nextstate <= S14;
endcase
```

Note S1 to S14 are part of an enum that holds 5 bits[4:0]. The rest are inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the result of ternary operation being assigned to a register.
Try rewriting it as below:

```
nextstate = (OpCode1) ? S2 : S1;
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Note that this is an enum so it is actually nextstate <= opCode1.

Comment: FYI: combinational logic should be assigned with a blocking assignment (`=`), not non-blocking (`<=`). non-blocking should be used to assign flops (both edge-sensitive flip-flops and level-sensitive latches). Enums allow do not determine if it should be blocking or non-blocking, it all depends how it is intended to be used.